# How to create website link on IE-MODE with Edge Browser

Tags: web, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge

I've to create a link to a website but i need it to open in IE-MODE using Edge Browser

I tried this  but doesn't work

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --ie-mode-test "https://mywebsite.com"
```

Comment: A web site forcing a user's browser to set itself to a mode is probably very unlikely but, with Windows, nothing would surprise me.

Comment: This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F52330_01/installation_guides/insbridge_rm_client_guide/Content/Guides_RateManager/Insbridge%20RateManager%20Client%20Setup%20Guide/Enable%20IE%20mode%20on%20Microsoft%20Edge.htm) may help you (look for **Method 1**)

Comment: If your purpose is just to stop Windows to redirect IE to Edge, this [link](https://www.technipages.com/stop-internet-explorer-redirects-to-microsoft-edge) may help you

Comment: How about the issue? May I know if you have got any chance to check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814491/how-to-create-website-link-on-ie-mode-with-edge-browser/74846113#74846113)? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a website in IE mode, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) to configure IE mode policies.

You can also refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list) to configure local site list for IE mode.

Please pay attention, adding sites to local site list to automatically render in IE mode will last for 30 days by default. Using IE mode policies to configure IE mode doesn't have time restriction.